# How to finish the old screen after go the new screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo

I am going to navigate from screen A to screen B and finish the old screen A.
In other words, I would like to go to the screen like android activity.

```
//Android Code
StartActivity(Intent);
finish();
```

I tried like this on react-native.

```
// A screen code
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
this.props.navigation.navigate(B);
```

It works but the screen(saying screen X) just before screen A appears in a blink, and then goes to screen B. This is not a good UX experience.
How can I go to screen B from screen A smoothly, without seeing screen X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the current route with a new one:

```
this.props.navigation.replace(B);
```